# saving frames from webcam stream

Tags: r, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, webcam

I would like a routine that systematically extracts and saves the frames from webcam footage to a local directory on my personal computer.

Specifically, I am trying to save frames from the webcam at Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone Natl. Park. (https://www.nps.gov/yell/customcf/geyser_webcam_updated.htm)

Ideally, I would like to:

1. be able to control the rate at which frames are downloaded (e.g. take 1 frame every minute)
2. use FFMPEG or R
3. Save the actual frame and not a *snapshot* of the webpage

Despite point 3 above, I've tried simply taking a *screenshot* in R using the package webshot:

```
library(webshot)
i=1
while(i<=2) { 
webshot('https://www.nps.gov/yell/customcf/geyser_webcam_updated.htm',delay=60,paste(i,'.png',sep=""))

i=i+1
}
```

However, from the above code I get these two images:

[image] 
[image]
Despite the delay in the webshot() function (60 seconds) the two images are the same not to mention the obvious play button in the middle.  This method also seems a bit of a *hack* as it is saving a snapshot of the website and not the frames themselves.

I am certainly open to to using more appropriate command line tools (I am just unsure of what they are).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a direct HLS playlist. Simply run `ffmpeg -i https://56cf3370d8dd3.streamlock.net:1935/nps/faithful.stream/playlist.m3u8 -vframes 1 out.png` every minute.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  If you put it in an answer, Ill immedietly accept.  Would you mind explaining how you identified that url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of the URL shows, under the video tag

```
<source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="//56cf3370d8dd3.streamlock.net:1935/nps/faithful.stream/playlist.m3u8">
```

The src identifies a HLS playlist. So, you can then run ffmpeg periodically to get an image output like this:

```
ffmpeg -i https://56cf3370d8dd3.streamlock.net:1935/nps/faithful.stream/playlist.m3u8 -vframes 1 out.png
```